# Retrieve DNS details using the email address entered

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a question which I cannot solve for quite a while now. Been looking everywhere and just can't seem to come up with a solution.

I need to create a batch file that will prompt the user for their email address. This email address will then be trimmed at the "@" character. The remaining domain will then be used in the "nslookup" command, but I want it to filter just the mail exchange servers.

Example:

"Cooldude@gmail.com"

Then the next bit is what I need:

"gmail.com"

I then need the following to occur:

```
nslookup  
set type=mx  
gmail.com
```

This is what I have thus far:

```
@echo off  
set /p email="Enter your email address : "  
call :findString email "@" pos  
echo.%pos%  
set ex=%email:~%-pos%%  
echo Email Exchange is: %ex%  
pause  

:findString  
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION  
set "pos="  
set "str=!%~1!"  
for /L %%a in (0,1,1023) do (  
    set "s=!str:~%%a!"  
    if not defined pos if "%~2!s:*%~2=!"=="!s!" set "pos=%%a"  
)  
ENDLOCAL & IF "%~3" NEQ "" SET "%~3=%pos%"  

GOTO:EOF
```

Thanx in advance! ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "email=Cooldude@gmail.com"
set "email=%email:*@=%"
echo %email%
endlocal
```